# No definition available for static const member with initializer?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, instantiation

Given:

```
template<class T>
struct S {
  static int const N = 1;
};

extern template class S<int>;

template<class T>
int f( T n ) {
  return n + S<T>::N; // line 10
}

int main() {
  return f(1);        // line 14
}

//template class S<int>; // intentionally commented out to trigger error
```

I get:

```
foo.cpp: In function ‘int f(T) [with T = int]’:
foo.cpp:10:   instantiated from ‘const int S<int>::N’
foo.cpp:10:   instantiated from ‘int f(T) [with T = int]’
foo.cpp:14:   instantiated from here
foo.cpp:10: error: explicit instantiation of ‘S<int>::N’ but no definition available
```

But **why** do I get the error?

1. The point of doing an explicit template instantiation declaration is so that the definitions can be *elsewhere*, yet the *compiler* (not the linker) gives an error.  (In a real application, the currently commented out explicit instantiation declaration would be in another translation unit anyway.)
2. In this case, the value has a *constant initializer* so the compiler can in theory simply use the value directly.
3. When I don't do the explicit template instantiation declaration, I (oddly) don't have to explicitly define `S<T>::N`.

This is with g++ 4.2.1 on Mac OS X 10.6.6.

Comment: Well you could use `enum { N = 1 };` instead of a `static const`.

Comment: @KennyTM: that doesn't answer the question.  Obviously, this example is a whittled-down example of my real code.  The real code needs an unsigned long set to ~0 and, AFAIK, enums can't be "unsigned".

Comment: I think this is just a compiler bug. It compiles fine with g++ 4.4.0 under mingw.

Comment: It looks like a compiler problem to me. Comeau and VC++ don't seem to have any problems with it (though if you un-comment the last line, VC++ complains about that instantiation not having `extern`, so it doesn't match the previous one.

Answer (score 2):

```
extern template class S<int>;
```

I think this line causes the error, as it tells the compiler to look for *explicit instantiation*  of `S<int>` somewhere, but no explicit instantiation exists. Hence the error.

Once you comment this line, I think the code should compile fine.

---

EDIT:

Well, see this : http://www.ideone.com/oQnOi

As I said, it compiles fine!

---

EDIT:

I think $9.4.2/4 (as quoted by **Mark B**) doesn't apply to the static members of class **templates**, as $14.5.1.3 [temp.static] doesn't mandate the static members to be defined at namespace scope:

> A definition for a static data member
>   **may be provided** in a namespace scope
>   enclosing the definition of the **static
>   member’s class template**.

The the example follows as,

```
template<class T> class X  { static T s; }; 
template<class T> T X<T>::s = 0;
```

Notice, it doesn't say *"must be provided"*, rather *"may be provided"*. So I think the definition of static members of class template at namespace scope is optional.

Comment: One could also interpret that as "may be provided" in the sense of the opposite of "may not be provided *at all*", not the opposite of "may be provided *elsewhere*".  Does the standard where else it would be allowed?

Comment: @Oli: I interpret that as *"may not be provided at all"*. I mean, the definition at namespace scope is optional.

Answer (score 2):

From 9.4.2/2:

> The declaration of a static data
>   member in its class definition is not
>   a definition and may be of an
>   incomplete type other than cvqualified
>   void. The definition for a static data
>   member shall appear in a namespace
>   scope enclosing the member’s class
>   definition. In the definition at
>   namespace scope, the name of the
>   static data member shall be qualified
>   by its class name using the ::
>   operator.

And from 9.4.2/4:

> If a static data member is of const
>   integral or const enumeration type,
>   its declaration in the class
>   definition can specify a
>   constantinitializer which shall be an
>   integral constant expression (5.19).
>   In that case, the member can appear in
>   integral constant expressions within
>   its scope. The member shall still be
>   defined in a namespace scope if it is
>   used in the program and the namespace
>   scope definition shall not contain an
>   initializer.

From these references we can infer ("...shall still be defined..." in 9.4.2/4) that if it's not defined then the program isn't well-formed.