# Why does declaring a "static const" member in a header file cause linker errors?

Tags: c++

I have a class declaration(.h file) like so:

```
struct MyClass {
    static const uint32_t SIZE = sizeof(MyType);
};
```

When linking my program together, I get linker errors for `MyClass::SIZE`. `nm` confirms that the symbol is undefined. http://forums.devshed.com/c-programming-42/linker-errors-undefined-reference-to-static-member-data-193010.html seems to address my problem, indicating that "class static objects must also be declared outside any function or class just like normal globals."

I have two questions:

1. Is this explanation valid for my case? If so, can you explain in a little more detail why this is true?
2. What's the best way to fix it? I'd like to keep this member's initialization entirely in the .h file.

Comment: You're getting a lot of questionable and/or incomplete answers to this question.  Review my response before selecting.

Comment: Crazy Eddie: Your solution is correct. I am never taking the address of the member. Thanks for your explanation!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem may have nothing to do with someone taking the address of your variable.  It could simply be the compiler opting not to use the variable as a constant expression even though it could.  For example:

```
f(int const&);
struct X { enum { enum_val = 42 }; static int const static_mem = 42; };

f(5);
f(X::enum_val);
f(X::static_mem);
```

In the first two cases the compiler is required to use the input as a constant expression and the `const&` can be initialized with such.  The last case however is different.  Even though your intent is probably to use `static_mem` as a constant expression, and its completely legitimate to do so, the compiler is free to do otherwise and some will actually create a reference to the variable itself.  This is "use" of the variable and thus you're required to have a definition of that variable somewhere in the program.

There's two ways to fix this issue:

1) Add a definition to your program.

2) Use enum instead:
    struct X
    {
      enum { static_mem = ? };
    };

The first solution is necessary if you ever do intend that taking the address of your variable be possible.  Chances are though that you did not or you would have created that definition already.  The later solution forces the compiler to use `X::static_mem` as a constant expression since enum members don't actually exist as objects in the program.  Based on your last statement in your question, I'm betting this is the solution you really want.

Comment: Thank you for the clear, detailed, and *correct* answer :). I was never taking the address of the variable, and your second solution solves my problem!

Comment: Or, option 3 as an ugly hack, call the function with `f(X::static_mem + 0);` to make it behave like the `f(5);`. Option 1 seems best though.

Comment: @Bo - interesting hack, never thought of it.  I prefer option two for integrals I intend to be constant expressions though.

Comment: This is subtly wrong: The compiler does not opt to use the member as a compile time constant or not. When in the code above you type `f(5);` the expression `5` is an rvalue. For the compiler to bind the constant reference to the rvalue it has to *create* an lvalue, and what is actually done is that a variable is allocated and the constant reference is bound to that. Now in the case of `f(X::static_mem)`, the subexpression `X::static_mem` is already a constant lvalue, and the reference is directly bound to it --taking the address of the object under the hood.

Comment: Again, if you use `f( X::static_mem + 0 )`, as @Bo suggests, then the subexpression is an rvalue, and the same process is applied: an object is created with the return value, and the address of that object is used to bind the variable.

Comment: Another, slightly prettier hack is to `static_cast<int>(X::static_mem)` .

Answer (score 2):

The standard requires a definition for a static member integral constant only if its address is taken, otherwise the declaration with an initializer (what you have) is enough. That linker error message should mention which object/function takes an address of `MyClass::SIZE`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Do you have a solution to the problem, given that I'd like to constrain all assignments to the member to the `.h` file?

Comment: Either make `MyClass` a template to relax One Definition Rule and put an out of class definition of the static member in the header. Or, simpler, make that constant a namespace-scope constant, not a static member of the class.

Comment: I know well enough to avoid creating templates at all costs :). The inherited codebase I'm using unfortunately does not have namespaces at all. I will just move the `static const int` outside of the class, and keep it in the header file.

Comment: `const int` is enough. const for namespace-scope variables make them static.

Comment: A static member function will do as well.

Comment: Or, make it `enum { SIZE = sizeof(MyType) };`

Answer (score 1):

If you've to do this:

```
//.h file
struct MyClass 
{
    static const uint32_t SIZE = sizeof(MyType); //this is declaration!

}; 

//.cpp file
const uint32_t MyClass::SIZE; //this is definition - necessary!
```

Comment: +1, deleted my reply. Yours puts in code what I was writing: The problem is not the declaration, but that you actually combined declaration and definition. Assign the value within the .cpp (or .cxx or whatever) file and this problem will be resolved.

Comment: @Nawas, No I did not downvote. @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED: I include the header file in a variety of places, and would like to keep assignment constrained to one location. Is there no way to do this from the `.h` file?

Comment: @Mike: If you do this, then it is enough. No matter in how many places you include the header, as long as you define the variable!

Comment: @Mike It's necessary to always have a definition because of 9.4.2/4, see my answer.

Comment: class static integer constants are special, they only need to be defined if they are used, where *used* basically means that the address is taken. If the address is not taken, the compiler can and should use the value in the declaration (in the question code) as a compile time constant, without the static constant being defined.

Comment: @Mike: I'm not aware of one other than the one presented here. You could, of course `#ifdef` out the part with the assignment and `#define` the corresponding macro when including in one particular file if you really have to keep it inside the .h file. But these are just preprocessor workarounds that will not invalidate what was said in Nawaz' and my reply.

Comment: @Nawaz: I'm not able to parse "then it is enough" :). Can you explain? Can I put `const uint32_t MyClass::SIZE = sizeof(MyType)` right below the class declaration in the `.h` file?

Comment: @Mike: No. That will give an error *multiple definitions of the variable* if you include the .h file in multiple .cpp files!

Comment: @Mike: I modified my code. I initialized the variable in the class itself, as you did, but still defining it the .cpp file. Try this. It will work!

Comment: Unfortunately, the constant is used from other `.h` files. I'm afraid to ask: What's the solution here?

Comment: @Mike: Could you please tell us what problem you're facing? And is it not compiling? Or what?

Comment: @Nawaz Well, I am just noticing that I use the constant in other `.h` files, and wondering what to do. I haven't tried to compile the program yet with any of the suggestions here.

Comment: @Mike: If you don't try compiling what we're suggesting here, then what is the point of asking question?

Comment: @Nawaz: Of course I am going to try what you're suggesting :). I just want to figure out the complete solution before trying to implement it.

Comment: @Mike: What I suggested is complete. Try compiling and let us know if you still face any problem!

Comment: @Nawaz: Erm, I don't think it is. Several `.h` files use `MyClass::Size`; if a `.cpp` file includes one of those `.h` files, without a declaration, then how will the linker errors be resolved, aside from adding the declaration to _EVERY_ `.cpp`file?

Comment: @Mike: Did you try compiling?

Comment: @Nawaz: Just because it works now, doesn't mean it will work down the road, either when my codebase changes or when I change compilers. I want to find the right solution, as based on the C++ standard, not just get it to work for the time being with my current code using my current compiler.

Comment: @Mike: It will work. It's standard conformant. I don't see any problem. And what you're saying doesn't make sense at all. Once you *define* the variable in just ONE .cpp file, then all other .cpp files use that definition. Linker will be able to link it. Just think about how you declare function in .h file, and define it .cpp file, yet you include the .h file in multiple source files and linker find the definition of functions!

Answer (score 1):

Quoting myself from [No definition available for static const member with initializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5032683/no-definition-available-for-static-const-member-with-initializer/5032811#5032811)

And from 9.4.2/4:

> If a static data member is of const
>   integral or const enumeration type,
>   its declaration in the class
>   definition can specify a
>   constant initializer which shall be an
>   integral constant expression (5.19).
>   In that case, the member can appear in
>   integral constant expressions within
>   its scope. **The member shall still be
>   defined in a namespace scope if it is
>   used in the program** and the namespace
>   scope definition shall not contain an
>   initializer.

From these references we can infer ("...shall still be defined..." in 9.4.2/4) that if it's not defined then the program isn't well-formed.

@David Rodríguez - dribeas points out that you must be taking the address of the static member in your program somewhere. If you can avoid taking the address then there's no need for the definition in the implementation file (alternately you aren't taking the address and have a buggy compiler). Otherwise you must have the definition.

Comment: Nice quoting, but it does not apply to the question. **There is an initializer in the declaration.**

Comment: @Maxim: it applies to the question, and the problem OP is facing. +1 for the quotation!

Comment: The issue that you are missing from the answer is what is the definition of *used* in the standard. Basically, for static const integer members of a class *used* means that the address is taken (either to obtain a pointer or reference). There is no need to *define* the member if the address is not taken.

Comment: @David: Most likely, the OP is using it outside the class as well.

Comment: @David Rodríguez - dribeas do you happen to know the standard section that defines used?

Comment: @Mark B - David is wrong.  In some respect he is correct, any use of a variable requires using its address, that's what variables look like once compiled.  However, he doesn't seem to mean this but instead explicitly taking the address of the variable.  This is not necessary for "use" of the variable.  For example, depending on compiler, use of the variable in a min or max expression can be "using" the variable.  Somewhere deep in my answer stack is an example of such happening to someone.

Comment: I've seen this too many times: people post quotes from the standard and then have difficulty explaining them in plain language.

Comment: The crux of the issue is that a `const&` parameter can be initialized with a constant expression, so passing a static integral member shouldn't "use" that member right?  Wrong.  The real answer is, it depends on what the compiler decides to do.  This is one reason why using enums instead of static integrals is better in almost every case.

Comment: @Crazy Eddie: the `const &` parameter is a really bad and misleading example, in particular with `void foo( const int & );` if you call `foo( 5 )` (with a literal, which is a constant expression), the compiler has to create a local variable that will then be bound to the argument. On the other hand, if you have `foo( x::my_const_int )` the compiler will *get the address* of the element and use that. No extra object will be created, and that forces the *use* of the member.

Comment: Simple test: `void foo( const int & x ) { std::cout << &x << std::endl; } struct test { static const int x = 1; }; const int test::x; int main() { foo( 1 ); foo( 1 ); foo( 1 ); foo( test::x ); foo( test::x ); foo( test::x ); std::cout << &test::x << std::endl; }` The output will most probably contain three different pointers into the stack and then three copies of the same pointer into `test::x`

Comment: To spell it out: passing the static constant member as a constant reference is equivalent to acquiring a pointer --which is how references are implemented in many cases.

Comment: Just another comment... as if I had not written enough here today. Not all uses of a variable require taking the address. In particular whenever a rvalue can be used, that does not require taking the address of the object. If the function took the parameter by value, as in `void foo( int )`, then the construction of the parameter from the argument (as in a call `foo( test::x )`) does not require an lvalue, but rather an rvalue, and that call does not constitute an *use* of the `test::x` static member.

Comment: @Mark B: 3.2/2 *An expression is potentially evaluated unless it appears where an integral constant expression is required
(see 5.19), is the operand of the sizeof operator (5.3.3), or is the operand of the typeid operator and the expression does not designate an lvalue of polymorphic class type (5.2.8) An object or non-overloaded function is used if its name appears in a potentially-evaluated expression.* Then again, it was not considered to be clear enough and there is a DR (defect report)

Comment: @Mark B: It has been rephrased in the C++0x drafts as *An expression is potentially evaluated unless it is an unevaluated operand (Clause 5) or a subexpression thereof. A variable or non-overloaded function whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression is used unless it is an object that satisfies the requirements for appearing in a constant expression (5.19)  and the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) is immediately applied.* Where the last bit is what says that binding to a constant reference constitutes **use**

Answer (score -1):

1. Most likely, but without any error messages, it's hard to say.
2. Use a static const int. You can initialize it in the header, and you don't need to declare it in the cpp.

Comment: For (2), do you mean outside the class?

Comment: Nope, inside. Replace your uint32_t by an int, should work (well, it works on my mingW g++ compiler).

Comment: Why is that the case? I'm on a 32-bit platform; shouldn't `uint32_t` be equivalent to `int`?

Comment: It is equivalent for you (and, yes, it is "logically" equivalent). But it is not for the compiler. The static const int rule is there to make your life easier, or declaring numerical constant could be really painful. The same rule for float, double and others numerical types would have been great, though.

Comment: Can you explain why it is not equivalent to the compiler? Pointers to the C++ standard would be great!

Comment: Honestly, I can't, and I don't know well enough the standard to give you a good answer :). But I'm sure someone here will tell you !